# Javascript subtract one day from "yyyy-mm-ss" string IN UTC TIMEZONE

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, timezone

I have a string for a UTC date `var latestDate='2020-11-17'` , and I'm trying to get the previous days date from this string into a new variable `var subtractedDate;`.

So my goal is to get `subtractedDate=2020-11-16`

```js
var latestDate='2020-11-17';
//convert to iso date string                  
var dateStr = new Date(latestDate).toISOString();                         
console.log('dateStr=', dateStr);                                          
//subtract a day

//ERROR OCCURS HERE, has trouble running // var subtractedDate = dateStr.setDate(('2020-11-17T00:00:00.000Z').getDate()-1);, something with how I have '2020-11-17T00:00:00.000Z' formatted?

var subtractedDate = dateStr.setDate(dateStr.getDate()-1);                                  
console.log('subtractedDate  = ', subtractedDate);
```

I am trying to use `('2020-11-17T00:00:00.000Z').getDate()-1` to subtract a day from the datetimestamp but it causes an error saying `Uncaught TypeError: dateStr.getDate is not a function`

Comment: You're just grabbing the wrong variable in `var exDateMinusDay = exDate;`. Your result is in `dateStr`, not `exDate`. (I'd also suggest adding a `Z` to the end of `exDate` when parsing it, e.g. `var dateStr = new Date(exDate + "Z");`. Per spec it should be parsed in UTC, but the spec moved around a bit between ES2015 and ES2018 and some out-of-date browsers may read it as local time instead without the `Z`.)

Comment: it's not a date-string, it's a date object, and: `date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);` should work. It's just that you're printing the wrong thing... Also, please don't use `var`, we now have `let` and `const` which are preferred!

Comment: As of your edit fixing the issue I pointed out above, it works. What's the question?

Comment: edited my question, the code snippit works yes, but when I run it locally in a node.js project, it picks up my local timezone

Comment: @Martin - Per spec, your code is correct and uses UTC, but see my first comment above -- it may be best to add a `Z` when parsing to be sure. (`toISOString` always uses UTC.)

Comment: If I add a `Z` character to my dateTime like so: `var dateStr = new Date("2020-11-17Z");` it still returns dateStr as `Mon Nov 16 2020 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)`

Comment: @Martin - Right, but `toISOString` will give you the correct date (`new Date("2020-11-17Z").toISOString()` results in `"2020-11-17T00:00:00.000Z"`). JavaScript `Date`s are weird: They always represent X milliseconds since The Epoch in UTC. Then they have some methods (`toString`, `getHours`, etc.) that convert that to your local timezone and give you information in that timezone, and other methods (`toISOString`, `getUTCHours`) that give you UTC information. ...

Comment: ... If you parse in UTC (which the `Z` ensures even though it shouldn't be necessary on a date-only string like yours) and you get the result in UTC (from `toISOString`), you're all set.

Comment: (Side note - if you don't `@`-notify me, I don't get a notification that you've responded. SO only does automatic notifications when you're the post author or you're the only other person in the comments other than the post author. Since there's a comment above from someone else, it won't auto-notify.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder updated my question again,I can get the UTC date fine (i think?) using `.toISOString` (although I'm wondering if this is the same as getting it in UTC, becaue arent iso and utc different things?). But I am getting an error when I try to subtract a day from my utc datetime string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224656/discussion-between-martin-and-t-j-crowder).

Comment: also can I reopen this question or should I make a new one?

Comment: @Martin - I don't believe in the "chat" thing when the discussion is germane to the question. There's no reason to reopen this, your original code worked, you just had the wrong variable. Yes, ISO and UTC are different things, but as I've said above twice, **`toISOString` uses UTC**. Re the most recent edit: Strings don't have a `getDate` function.

Comment: [Here's your original code updated to use the right variable](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/bej81tdo/), adding a Z, and with a few names fixed, missing semicolons added, and unnecessary `()` removed.

Answer (score 1):

We should be able to use [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) to get the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC, then subtract 1 days worth of milliseconds (24*60*60*1000) to get the unix time one day earlier.

We can then use [Date.toLocaleTimeString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) to format it.

```js
const latestDate='2020-11-17';
 
// Get the number of milliseconds since 1970-1-1, then subtract 1 day (24*60*60*1000 milliseconds)
const dt = new Date(Date.parse(latestDate) - 24*60*60*1000);
// Format an ISO-8601 date in the UTC timezone
const subtractedDate = dt.toLocaleDateString('sv', { timeZone: 'UTC' });

console.log({ latestDate, subtractedDate })
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try as follows.

```
dateStr.setDate(dateStr.getDate()-1);
var dateStr = new Date();
var month = dateStr.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
var day = dateStr.getUTCDate();
var year = dateStr.getUTCFullYear();
newdate = year + "/" + month + "/" + day;
```

Comment: just updated me question, there was a small type in my codeblock, the sample code runs correctly here but when i run it locally it picks up my timezone (see my edited question)

Comment: var month = dateStr.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
var day = dateStr.getUTCDate();
var year = dateStr.getUTCFullYear();
exDate = year + "/" + month + "/" + day;

Comment: Try to edit directly in your question and point out the edits for cleaner format.